# Calculating Mass Inertia Matrix in Joint Space

Tags: ros, rospy, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am doing simulation of Baxter Robot. Hence I need to calculate Mass Inertia Matrix in Joint Space. I have Baxter URDF files. I see [here](https://studywolf.wordpress.com/2013/09/07/robot-control-3-accounting-for-mass-and-gravity/) that  Mass Inertia Matrix in Joint Space is defined in following way-
[image: image description]

However I am not sure, whether it is possible to get this matrix directly by using URDF file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246937/calculating-mass-inertia-matrix-in-joint-space/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2016-11-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One option is to create a robot model from [KDLKinematics](http://wiki.ros.org/pykdl_utils) based on the URDF. This package can compute the Jacobian and mass matrix using the following functions from [here](https://github.com/gt-ros-pkg/hrl-kdl/blob/hydro/pykdl_utils/src/pykdl_utils/kdl_kinematics.py): jacobian() and inertia(). You would have to change the end_link when calling the KDLKinematics() function for calculating jacobian() and inertia() for different chains.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-11-02**:
Perfect. This is what I was  looking for. One quick question, by looking at [cart_inertia](https://github.com/gt-ros-pkg/hrl-kdl/blob/hydro/pykdl_utils/src/pykdl_utils/kdl_kinematics.py#L305) function, I am confused. The Joint Space matrix defined above looks like cartesian space matrix. Isn't it?